# XSLT: How to loop through unique nodes with multiple identical subnodes and select only one specific subnode

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Attempting to use a for-each loop through this code block returns all 3 values into one output. How would one go about selecting only one of these elements, say, data on Elise?

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>
      <Name>Jonathan</Name>
      <Age>56</Age>
      <Sex>Male</Sex>
    </C>
    <C>
      <Name>Elise</Name>
      <Age>50</Age>
      <Sex>Female</Sex>
    </C>
    <C>
      <Name>Adam</Name>
      <Age>47</Age>
      <Sex>Male</Sex>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select the node set for `Elise` you can match a template accordingly.

```
<xsl:template match="C[Name='Elise']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The above template will select a node `C` having child node `Name` with the value as `Elise`. It will then copy the node `C` and all the children to give an output as below.

```
<C>
    <Name>Elise</Name>
    <Age>50</Age>
    <Sex>Female</Sex>
</C>
```

P.S. Please correct the shared XML for the closing tags as it looks like a copy-paste issue. The XML is not a well-formed one.

Comment: Hi Aniket,
Thank you for a helpful response. Unfortunately, I won't always know what name the values will take on. 
I think my solution should generate a unique id number for each C element, and then allow me to pick from only one of these.

Comment: The requirement is not very clear. Location of an element can be determined by different ways viz. value, index, preceding/descending nodes, etc. Everything depends on your requirement and the desired output.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion, my first post here.
I need to select a certain return number from this xml string in xslt 1.0 without knowing its value beforehand. I think the correct solution is to, in some way, attach an id to the string and then call from it. So for instance, Elise should have a string id attached to her node, from which I could call @ID='2'.

Comment: Welcome to SO. XSLT internally uses an `index` starting from `1` when looping through the nodes having same names, similar to arrays. E.g. In this case, node `C` will be internally assigned an `index` and `C[2]/Name` will return `Elise`. The `index` value can be accessed by the XSLT function `position()`. The value of `position()` can then be used wherever required. I would suggest you look up for [XSLT Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp) to understand the features of XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Anikets' respose I figured that my solution was to call the subnode from its 'hidden' index:

<xsl:for-each select="($A/B/C/Name)[2]">
    <print>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </print>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The above returns only the value 'Elise'